# "Please ensure that the GDAL_DATA environment variable is set and try again" on Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu

I'm having a problem loading the 'convert os gml to ogr' plugin in QGIS 1.8 running on (k)ubuntu 12.10.

Basically, clicking the plugin prompts the error:

```
"Please ensure that the GDAL_DATA environment variable is set and try again"
```

I've tried setting the environment variable via instructions here: (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable) with the terminal command "export GDAL_DATA=/usr/share/gdal/1.9"
but to no avail (i'm not even sure this is the right course of action...)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install GDAL and QGIS using the package manager? Are you sure, your GDAL installation is in default directories?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Well, qgis (1.8) was installed via package manager (muon) following the adding of the precise repository listed on the qgis website. 
I don't recall intentionally installing gdal, so i assume it installed along with other dependencies.
Gdal appears to be in /usr/share/gdal/1.9, which i assume is the default directory.

Comment: How about the gdal python bindings?  Available via the geospatial repository - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable

Comment: Thanks, but i'm already using that ppa to allow installation of qgis-1.8. checked the python bindings, and even tried downgrading from 1.9.2 to 1.9.0, but the same error message is reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. Environment variables needed setting according to the KDE (rather than plain ubuntu) method.
Using the instructions here (http://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables/en) i created a script called 'gdal-qgis.sh' that contained just "export GDAL_DATA=/usr/share/gdal/1.9", and saved it to $HOME/.kde/env. Rebooted, and i can now convert.

Comment: Is it possible to add a 'Solved' tag?

Comment: If you want to set the variable for all users add export GDAL_DATA=/usr/share/gdal/1.9 to a new line in your /etc/environment file.  This would be a good place for it if you ever decide to switch from KDE to a different desktop.

Comment: A "solved tag" is added by clicking the green Accept checkmark.